# How to show a default value in dropdown using JQuery when page loads

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, default

Now on page load I need to select United States as my default value.

The code for that I am writing is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("input[name='contactAddress.id']").val() == "") {

        $(contactAddress.country).find('option').filter(function() {
            return this.text == 'United States';
        }).attr('selected','selected');
        $(contactAddress.country).val('United States');
    }
});
```

Dropdown Code :

```
 <tr>
            <th><s:text name="contactAddress.country"/>:</th>
            <td>
                <v:list var="countries" action="country" namespace="/"/>
                <s:select name="contactAddress.country"
                    value="contactAddress.country.id"
                    headerKey="" 
                    headerValue="-- Please Select --" 
                    list="countries"
                    listKey="id" 
                    listValue="name"/>                                                      
                <s:fielderror><s:param>contactAddress.country</s:param></s:fielderror>              
            </td>
            <th><s:text name="contactAddress.zipPostalCode"/>:</th>
            <td><s:textfield name="contactAddress.zipPostalCode" /></td>
        </tr>
```

But this is not working. I have been googling and tried many different syntaxes for that matter but nothing is working. Where Am I going wrong .Please help

Comment: You would have to use the generated name for `$("input[name='contactAddress.id']")` which is probably not `contactAddress.id`

Comment: contactAddress.id is just to check if it's a new contact address.The main problem is with the country related to the contact address.

Comment: adding an ID to the select value would make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try

```
$("select[name='contactAddress.country']")
```

instead of

```
$(contactAddress.country)
```

also you know that just writing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("input[name='contactAddress.id']").val() == "") {
       $("select[name='contactAddress.country']").val('United States');           
    }
});
```

handles changing of the dropdown selected item

note :

jquery isn't understanding this

```
$('#contactAddress.country')
```

that is looking for the child of "contactAddress" with a class of "country"

Comment: @user2820678 - actually - try taking the period out of your name , that is probably confusing jquery , it is looking for a child of #contactAddress with a class of "country"

Comment: Thanks Scott  $("select[name='contactAddress.country']").val('United States');   worked :)

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("input[name='contactAddress.id']").val() == "") {

    var element = document.getElementById('#contactAddress.country');
    element.value = 'United States';

    }
});
```

you might not need the # in the ID name

Comment: dprogramz :: Even I thought that would but Unfortunately even this isn't working.What could be the reason because this is one thing I have been using since long now but still :(

Comment: after looking at your HTML, you could try document.getElementsByName instead of ID. or add id="contactAddress.country" to your select tag.